# Mongoose: grab document with certain property.length > 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to grab a list of movies from the server using Mongoose, but I only want the movies where the property *ratings* has actual values stored in it (*ratings* is an array). I tried the way below using `.where('ratings.length').gt(0)` but it didn't filter it right as the movies with a rating don't get through. Does anyone know the right way to do this?

```
 Movie.find()
            .where('ratings.length').gt(0)
            .sort({averageRating:1})
            .limit(100)
            .exec(function(err, movies){
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        message: "An error occurred",
                        obj: err
                    })
                }
                res.status(200).json({
                    Message: "success",
                    obj: movies
                })
            })
```

**Image of documents in mongodb**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$where` like this:

```
Movie
    .$where('this.ratings.length > 0')
    .sort({
        averageRating: 1
    })
    .limit(100)
    .exec(function (err, movies) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "An error occurred",
                obj: err
            })
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            Message: "success",
            obj: movies
        })
    })
```

After Mongo 2.2+, you can also do this for better efficiency:

```
Movie.where('ratings.1').exists()
```

Comment: I get the following error when I tried this: "ReferenceError: ratings is not defined :↵@:1:15↵"

Comment: Do you have `ratings` in your document?

Comment: Yes, every movie document has a ratings property.

Comment: I tried the one at the bottom, but that one returns an empty array even though I added a rating to one of the movies.

Comment: I added a picture of an example document to the original post.

Comment: Hey.. I missed `this` in the `$where` query. Try again with `this`?

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm now. Just one more question. What is the difference between $where and .where? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: `where` is a mongoose thing. A syntax sugar over the regular `find` method. Ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#where_where `$where` is the native MongoDB implementation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-$where

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help sir. I really appreciate it. Have a nice day.